# VS Code Julia REPL very slow startup

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, vscode-extensions

I installed julia with juliaup from the windows store (win 11), then installed Julia 1.8.2. Everything works fine in the Julia shell. I installed the **vscode julia extension**.
I was trying to use the VS Code REPL feature but it takes ~1/2 min to start each time getting stuck in the LanguageServer startup.

```
  Activating project at `c:\Users\aless\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.38.2\scripts\environments\languageserver\v1.8`
[ Info: Starting the Julia Language Server
[ Info: Symbol server store is at 'c:\Users\aless\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\julialang.language-julia\symbolstorev5'.
[ Info: Starting LS at 1668364752
[ Info: Received new data from Julia Symbol Server.
```

The `Starting LS at 1668364752` takes the most time.
I don't have any package yet, everything is clean. Another thing is that VS Code opens the REPL immediately, if I do ctrl+enter on the lines they are not sent to the REPL until the server has started.
After the REPL is activated everything is fast.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've made a Github Issue if you need: https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/3155